# Meteor node-simple-schema allowedValues/custom functions

Tags: meteor, database-schema

I'm trying to make two fields interdependent using [Adeed node-simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js) like this:

`const Schemas = {};`

```
Schemas.User= new SimpleSchema({
  name: { type: String },
  surname: { 
    type: String, 
    allowedValues(){
      if ( this.field('name').value === "Daniel" ) {
        return SomeCollection.find().fetch().map(obj => ...)
      }
    }
});
```

But it's not possible to use `this.field` and other function specefic to `custom()` inside `allowedValues()`.
What I want: make `allowedValues` to depend on what the user put in the `name` field ( `this.field('name').value === "Daniel"` ). Or is it possible to use `allowedValues` inside `custom()`?

```
custom(){ 
  ...
  return allowedValues; // limit what the user can provide to the field.
}
```

**Note:** I'm using [UniForms](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms) not [AutoForm](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/tree/master).

Comment: Do you use it in combination with `AutoForm` if so you should put that into your question.

Comment: Hi @Jankapunkt, no I'm using it with AutoForm, rather with UniForm.

Comment: Good to know for others. I by the way have a similar issue with `autoValue` in uniforms so I am interested in a good answer. Can you please extend your question by the fact that you use uniforms?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem on the client using `UniForms`.
This is how i got the field value:

```
<AutoForm 
 schema={ Schemas.User } 
 onChangeModel={ model =>  ( 
   model.name ? this.setState({ name: model.name }) : ''
  )}
 ...
>
...
</Autoform>
```

Using `onChangeModel={ model.name ? this.setState({ name: model.name }) : '' )}` I'm able to store the value of name anytime the model changes. [Reference](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/blob/master/API.md#autoform)
I think one can also use [findValue](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#guaranteed-props). But i did not tried it since `onChangeModel` satisfied my needs.